# How do I interpret b and c in this union of sets question?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been set the question:
(2) Let A,B, and C be sets with the following properties:(a)|A|= 100,|B|= 50,and|C|= 48.(b) The number of elements that belong to exactly one of the three sets is twice the number that belong to exactly two of the sets.(c) The number of elements that belong to exactly one of the three sets is three times the number that belong to all of the sets.How many elements belong to all three sets?

I'm having a hard time interpreting b and c, as b could imply whats exclusively in A (or B or C) = 2|BnC| (or with others) or |A|= 2|BnC|, and C doesn't use exactly in the final part i.e. 'exactly' all three sets what would imply |AnBnC| however it doesn't do this hence I'm left wondering what the use of exactly would mean in the rest of the question, with not much I can do apart from working out all possible ways to do this and assume one is correct in the end. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Hi Shaun, my apologies for the lack of clarification first of all, however, on that page you sent. The first point of advice is to make the title the question, which is what I originally did by how do I answer this question. The second is referring to something I am unaware of hence I will check this and how it would've helped me ask the question better. The third doesn't help much as my set question takes around 350 characters and reduced to b and c alone: 250. The fourth, I wouldn't consider myself as a good advertiser of my question however I did consider this and thought that my original

Comment: question would entice whoever saw it to check the contents of the question and read it to see how they would interpret the question. The fifth I believe I have stuck to, as my question without the title fully described what I am asking. I'm aware that my original question wasn't good and will do better in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I like to do is divide it into 8 distinct disjoint all encompassing sets.  They are:

1) $A\cap B \cap C$.    These are the only elements in all three sets. This is one of the variables we are asked about.  Lets say there are $x$ elements. This are also some of the elments that compose $A$, $B$ or $C$.

> $x =|A\cap B\cap C|$ is the element of elements in all three set. .

2) $A\cap B \cap C^c$. ($C^c$ means $C$'s complement.  All the elements not in see).  These are some but not all elements that are in exactly $2$ sets.  We'll call this $d$ elements. These are also some of the elements in $A$ and $B$.

3) $A \cap B^c \cap C$.  Call this number $e$.

4) $A^c \cap B \cap C$. Call this number $f$.

> Sets 2-4 are all the elements in exactly two sets.  $d+e+f=$ number of elements in exactly two sets..

5) $A^c\cap B^c \cap C$.  Call this number $g$.

6) $A^c \cap B \cap C^c$. Call this number $h$

7) $A \cap B^c \cap C^c$. Call this number $i$

> Sets 5-7 are the sets with elements in exactly one set.  $g+h+i\le 100$ is the number of elements in exactly one set.

8) $A^c\cap B^c \cap C^c$.  These are the elements not in any of the sets.  This will not have anything to do with our work.

> Sets 1) 2) 3) and 7) make up the elements of $A$ so $|A| = 100=x + d+e + i$.
>
> Sets 1) 2) 4) and 6) make up the elements of $B$ so $|B| = 50  = x + d+ f + h$.
>
> Sets 1) 3) 4) and 5) make up the elements of $C$ so $|C| = 48 = x + e+f +g$.

and we know

> $g+h+i = 2(d+e +f)$
>
> $g+h+i = 3x$.

5 equations and 7 unknowns. But we are only asked to solve for $x$, and we have restrictions.

Adding $|A| + |B|+|C|$ together we get.

$198 = 3x + 2(d+e+f) + (g+h+i)$

Substituting $2(d+e+f)=(g+h+i) = 3x$ we get

$198 = 3x + 3x  +3x = 9x$

and $x = 22$.

We aren't asked to solve anything more.

Comment: Thank you very much, this answered my question perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V=A\cup B\cup C$. Then for any set $S$, we can define a map $1_S\colon V\to \Bbb Z$ given by
$$1_S(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\in S\\0&\text{if }x\notin S\end{cases} $$
With this, we can define the map $\operatorname{ct}\colon V\to \Bbb Z$ as
$$\operatorname{ct}(x)=1_A(x)+1_B(x)+1_C(x). $$
It counts, in how many of the three given sets an element is. Then we can let $$f(n):=|\{\,x\in V\mid \operatorname{ct}(x)=n\,\}|$$
be the number of elements that are in exactly $n$ sets.
With this, condition b) and c) amount to
$$f(1)=2f(2)\qquad f(1)=2f(3).$$